# How can I delete my "160by2" account?

Tags: account-management

How can I completely delete my [160by2](http://www.160by2.com/) account?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According [the FAQ](http://www.160by2.com/faq.aspx) - you just need to send them an email along with your mobile number requesting they close your account.

> **How do I close my 160by2 account?**
>
> We’re sorry to see you go. Please feel
>   free to let us know your user
>   experience on 160by2 or any issue due
>   to which you chose to close your
>   160by2 account on our feedback page.
>   You can close your 160by2 account by
>   sending a mail requesting to close
>   your 160by2 account along with your
>   mobile number registered with us to
>   [160by2@smscountry.com](http://mailto:160by2@smscountry.com).

Answer (score -1):

It is impossible to delete your 160by2 account. You only have not login for at least 6 months and after that it will automatically deleted.